# SQL Server 2008 - "Enhanced read-ahead and scan"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can anyone point me to, or does anyone know what this "feature" of SQL Server is? Googling for it (also for "Super scan" which seems to be a synonym for the feature) reveals no information other than all the edition comparison pages that exist out there for SQL Server.

I'm also not sure whether this is a stackoverflow or a serverfault question. I'll try here on serverfault first, but if folk think stackoverflow may be a better forum, drop me a comment to that effect - ta :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lol.. Superscan indeed!  Those crazy MS marketing guys!

This has long been an enterprise exclusive feature for SQL Server and well worth the money if you ask me.  Try searching for merry-go-round scan, that should yield more results explaining what it does.

Comment: Top stuff -- ta :-)